# sql delete records based on combination of multiple fields in other table

Tags: sql

I realize the tables have the same two columns but I'm working with inflexible constraints so I can't change this structure.

**TableA**:

```
Host_ID | Carrier_ID 
111     |  222        /*Row 1*/
111     |  333        /*Row 2*/
```

**TableB**:

```
Host_ID | Carrier_ID      
111     |  222
```

I am working on a form that will fire off a javascript alert if a user attempts to delete the lead `carrier_id` from `TableA` through a web form.

I want to write a where clause in the delete statement that will prevent deletion of the row that appears both in `TableA` and `TableB` (in this case Row 1) because `TableB` stores all of the main carriers.

It would be perfectly ok to allow the user to delete Row 2 through the web form since the combination of that `Host_ID` and `Carrier_ID` does NOT exist in `TableB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
delete from tableA
    where not exists (select 1
                      from tableB b
                      where tableA.Host_Id = b.Host_Id and tableA.Carrier_Id = b.Carrier_id
                     );
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

EDIT:

If you want to remove particular values, with the check:

```
delete from tableA
    where Host_Id = $Host_Id and Carrier_Id = $Carrier_ID and
          not exists (select 1
                      from tableB b
                      where tableA.Host_Id = b.Host_Id and tableA.Carrier_Id = b.Carrier_id
                     );
```

Comment: I think so except I don't want to delete EVERY record from TableA that does NOT exist in TableB. I want to specify it by feeding variables into the sql query.  Would I need another statement in the where clause before the 'not exists' portion?

Comment: @lostinthebits . . . You would add additional clauses in the `where` to specify what you want to delete.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
DELETE tablea
FROM tablea a LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb b
ON a.host_id = b.host_id
AND a.carrier_id = b.carrier_id
WHERE
b.host_id IS NULL
AND b.carrier_id IS NULL
AND a.host_id = '<<your value here>>'
AND a.carrier_id = '<<your value here>>
```

This uses outer join to detect if matching row exists in tableb and allow delete when matching row does not exist

See illustration here [sql fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd4f8/4)